# Tkinter Mac About Dialog?

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, dialog

I'd like to have the option to add an "About" dialog for my Tkinter app on OS X. On Mac OS X, if you go to the name of the app > About [App Name] you get a popup dialog.

How to get to the dialog:

[image: How to get to the dialog]

What the dialog looks like:

[image: What the dialog looks like:]

I'd like to replace this with an about dialog that has information relevant to my application. This is defiantly possible, as it has been done in IDLE 3.4. The version of Python I am using is Python 3.4.1.

Thanks!

Comment: If it has been done in IDLE so open source code of IDLE and find it.

Comment: I don't use Mac but what happends when you add normal Tkinter menu in your application which open normal Tkinter window ? Did you try it ?

Comment: I found this: https://coderwall.com/p/h9v7va which I assume is to simply override the default tk command 'tkAboutDialog' with a custom method for your own about menu. I can't confirm/deny that this works as I am not currently in front of an osx machine, however it's worth a try.

Comment: 1. Where is the source for IDLE?

2. I'm not exactly sure what you mean.

3. I will try that! Thanks! :D